# Forced to use wss:// when behind proxy from https to http

Tags: nginx, neo4j

I have setup a nginx proxy to pass https url to internal http neo4j web. I can reach the neo4j login page without any issue, but I am forced to use the **neo4j+s/bolt+s** interface.

Just wondering how I can configure nginx to remove any ssl related info via proxypass module, in order to login in neo4j with ws, no wss?

Thanks,

Chance

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get rid of wss by adding another nginx proxy to set the https url as upstream server in location.proxy_pass. It won't show wss/neo4j+s/bolt+s any more once you visit the web by the http url. Hopefully it will help for anyone has the similar issue as me.